# ListViewItem.ForeColor Change Doesn't Display

Tags: c#, listview, colors, mousedown

**EDIT: I'm a dummy**

So... it turns out that the problem is in the following line;

```
item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
```

I had copied this line from another piece of code where I was just trying to change one `SubItem`, then I changed my mind and decided that here I wanted to change the whole row. My `listView` has a couple of hidden columns, and when `UseItemStyleForSubItems` is set to `false`, it only changes the first `SubItem`. So the change was probably happening the whole time, just not across the entire row.

Here's what `grayOut` looks like now:

```
    internal static void grayOut(ref ListView myLV)
    {
        //change each selected item to gray text
        //currently, multiselect is turned off, so this will only be one item at a time
        foreach (ListViewItem item in myLV.SelectedItems)
        {
            item.Selected = false;
            item.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            item.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            item.Font = new Font("MS Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Italic);
        }
    }
```

It was as easy as I thought it should be. :)

**Original Question**

I'm using the following code to change the `ForeColor` of items for which a selected action has already been performed.

```
     public partial claass MyForm: Form
     private void bgProgress_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
         Global.grayOut(ref this.lvUsers);
    }

    ...

    public static class Global

    internal static void grayOut(ref ListView myLV)
    {
        //change each selected item to gray text
        //currently, multiselect is turned off, so this will only be one item at a time
        foreach (ListViewItem item in myLV.SelectedItems)
        {
            item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
            item.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            item.Font = new Font("MS Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
            item.Selected = false;
        }

        myLV.Refresh();
    }
```

I have two problems.

1. The property changes, but that change does not display. In other words, I know that the `ForeColor` is changed to gray, because later I check to see if it is gray when the user tries to perform a certain action. However, it doesn't *appear* gray or italicized.
2. I'm also using the following to try and cancel a `MouseDown` event to keep the item from being selected again, but it still ends up being selected:

   ```
   private void lvUsers_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       // Make sure it was a single left click, like the normal Click event
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
           ListViewHitTestInfo htInfo = lvUsers.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
           if (htInfo.Item.ForeColor == Color.Gray)
           {
               return;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I haven't found any other method for cancelling a `MouseDown` event, so I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Where do you call the `grayOut`?

Comment: From `private void bgProgress_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Are there any exceptions being thrown in the output?

Comment: All the selecteditems have default `backcolor - blue` and `forecolor - white`, you can't change that easily.

Comment: @keyboardP, no exceptions.

Comment: @KingKing, I know I can change it easily when adding a new item, but it doesn't seem to be working to change existing items.

Comment: @tmoore82 no, changing the forecolor of one item is simple but when the item is **selected**, the normal forecolor is covered by the selected forecolor which is white by default.

Comment: @KingKing, that makes sense, but I change the value of `Selected` to `false`. Even when it's not selected, it shows up as black text on a white background.

Comment: @tmoore82 - What if you set the ForeColor after deselecting it?

Comment: @KingKing, I know the *property* is changing, because if I click the item after grayOut has been run, it returns true for the `if` statement in my `MouseDown` event. But it won't display as gray.

Comment: @keyboardP, I've swapped up the order of events every way I can think. Still not working.

Comment: @tmoore82 I tested your code with a `BackgroundWorker` and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you are after by relying on the method associated with the `SelectedIndexChanged Event`. Sample code:

```
private void myLV_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myLV.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in myLV.SelectedItems)
        {
            if (item.ForeColor == Color.Gray)
            {
                item.Selected = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewItem tempItem = item;
                grayOut2(ref tempItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code grays out any item you select if it hasn't been selected before (not grayed out); otherwise, it avoids it to be selected. `GrayOut2` is a version of your function only taking into consideration the given item.

```
internal static void grayOut2(ref ListViewItem item)
{
    //change each selected item to gray text
    //currently, multiselect is turned off, so this will only be one item at a time
    item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
    item.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    item.Font = new Font("MS Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
    item.Selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did solve the selection problem. However, the grayOut function still isn't changing the *display*. It changes the properties just fine. The `ForeColor` is gray, but the user can't see that it's gray. Could this have anything to do with multithreading?

Comment: @tmoore82 The font color should be updated immediately. In principle, multithreading problems involving GUI usually output an error; if you are using the right thread, there shouldn't be any problem. Cannot tell why the color is not being updated, but it has surely to do with your program. Create a new project from start, input a ListView and this code and you will see that it works without any problem.